# Delete null from otherwise duplicate row pair - mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization, select, null

A system is generating occasional similar row pairs, where all columns are the same except for `status_code`.  The dissimilar column pair contains a NULL and a numeric.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `delnull` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `process_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `somedate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_desc` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status_code` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `delnull`
--

INSERT INTO `delnull` (`id`, `process_id`, `somedate`, `status_desc`, `status_code`) VALUES
(1, 'xyz', '2012-11-12 10:01:43', 'Completed OK', 0),
(2, 'xyz', '2012-11-12 10:01:43', 'Completed OK', NULL),
(3, 'def', '2012-11-13 10:02:11', 'Failed: broken connection', 3),
(4, 'ghi', '2012-11-09 10:02:23', 'Lost packets', 4),
(5, 'ghi', '2012-11-01 10:04:30', 'Failed: broken connection', 3),
(6, 'ghi', '2012-11-06 10:04:23', 'Lost packets', 4),
(7, 'pos', '2012-11-02 10:06:01', 'Completed OK', 0),
(8, 'pos', '2012-11-02 10:06:02', 'Completed OK', NULL);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/128cc/1/0

What would be the best way of identifying the row containing the NULL value in status_code?  (in the data set, the row pair in question is #1 and #2, and I would need to identify #2 since it is the NULL value of this pair.

Comment: Why not just `SELECT id FROM delnull WHERE status_code IS NULL` ?

Comment: @acoder what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @eggyal - that would kill all null values including instances where there is not an otherwise similar row pair.  Ex, #8 would be deleted, where somedate is not a match with row #7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM delnull NATURAL JOIN (

  -- find all those groups that have both a NULL and a non-NULL record
  SELECT   process_id, somedate, status_desc
  FROM     delnull
  GROUP BY process_id, somedate, status_desc
  HAVING   SUM(status_code IS NOT NULL) AND SUM(status_code IS NULL)

) t WHERE delnull.status_code IS NULL
```

Comment: This works pretty good.  Took a second but I see what you are doing with the HAVING clause now - smart.  thanks.   SELECT version for example, if anyone else is interested:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/128cc/5/0

Answer (score -1):

Using a subquery do look for duplicates:

```
delete from `delnull` dn1
where dn1.status_code is null
and (
  select count(*) 
  from `delnull` dn2
  where dn2.id = dn1.id
  and dn2.process_id = dn1.process_id
  and dn2.somedate = dn1.somedate
  and dn2.status_code = dn1.status_code
   ) = 2
```

Comment: Changing that to SELECT results in:   MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/128cc/4/0